# How can I close the mail function in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, email

Every time I open the Terminal.app, it shows **You have new mail**. I want to know, how it is caused and how can I close the mail function.

I do not wish to see any mails and the above message when I launch the Terminal.app.

Answer (score 1):

To read the mail you have, use the `mail` command. `man mail` will give you instructions.

To delete all mail without reading it, run

```
sudo rm /var/mail/$USER/*
```

Comment: I know, but I what I want to do  is when I launch the Terminal.app, it never happens ever.

Comment: @HR.Jack When you read the email, what’s sending it?

Comment: Just the detail information